# Style of UpDown control doesn't match the Edit box

Tags: delphi, winapi, themes, edit

I am creating an Edit and an UpDown control using this code:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  Edit1 := CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 'EDIT', '',
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
    10, 10, 100, 24, Handle, 0, hInstance, nil);
  UpDown1 := CreateWindowEx (0, UPDOWN_CLASS, nil,
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or UDS_ALIGNRIGHT or UDS_ARROWKEYS
    or UDS_NOTHOUSANDS or UDS_HOTTRACK or UDS_SETBUDDYINT,
    0, 0, 0, 0, Handle, 0, hInstance, nil);
  SendMessage (UpDown1, UDM_SETBUDDY, Edit1, 0);
end;
```

The Edit looks like it has a 3D border, and UpDown doesn't.

[image: Screenshot 1]

**UPDATE:** (partially copy/pasted from my comment below)

Removing `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` from Edit makes it look just like a filled white rectangle (no border). Also, now the text in the Edit appears too high, so I will have to handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message or whatever it takes to fix it.

[image: Screenshot 2]

If I then add `WS_BORDER` flag, the result is almost what is desired, except that the gray color is darker than needed and then after certain user activity in the form (including hovering the edit with mouse cursor), an unnecessary vertical part of the border appears on the left of the UpDown control.

Third screenshot required at least 10 reputation to post it. Well, just imagine a vertical line going on the left edge of the up/down buttons. Its color is the same as the border, so I can suppose it's a part of the border.

Comment: Well, it has WS_EDGE_CLIENTEDGE and the other doesn't.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, yes, I thought about that too, should have mentioned. Probably thought after posting... Removing `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` from Edit makes it look just like a filled white rectangle (no border). If I then add `WS_BORDER` flag, the result is almost what is desired, except that the gray color is darker than needed and then after certain user activity in the form an unnecessary vertical part of the border appears on the left of the UpDown control. Screenshots: https://unsee.cc/dinamego/ https://unsee.cc/tizeposa/

Comment: This isn't really a delphi question. It's a pure Win32 question. You'd have solved all your problems by now if you'd done the job properly. With TnT controls.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, but `TTntUpDown` appears outside of the associated Edit. This is not the orthodox Windows style. I've seen various home-brew spin edits, but I want a normal, native one provided by Windows. Also, should I rename this question to "How do I change the border color of Edit control?" Because this seems to be the question now.

Comment: FWIW, the image seems to have been removed again?

Comment: The image link is already dead! Please edit the question to include the screenshot **inside** of the post using the image button of the StackOverflow editor. This will use imgur for *permanent* storage. I will remove my downvote then.

Comment: @zett42, I just couldn't find out how to do it... Now I know - Ctrl+G.

Comment: `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` is correct. Your edit control is unthemed, which means it isn't the Common Controls v6 one. Common Controls v6 handles `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` itself and draws the themed border, which is what the up-down control uses normally. I don't know anything about Delphi though, so I wouldn't know how to fix it (or if Delphi has recreated any of the functionality I described internally).

Comment: There is no reason to use the Win32 API directly when you can link [`TEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit) and [`TUpDown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TUpDown) together via the [`TUpDown.Associate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TUpDown.Associate) property. The UI you see is simply how Win32 UPDOWN controls look.

Comment: You might consider using Delphi's [`TSpinEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Samples.Spin.TSpinEdit) component instead, which displays arrows directly inside the edit field: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx5zZ.png

Comment: Thank you, @RemyLebeau. `TEdit` and `TUpDown` together look the same as `TTntEdit` together with `TTntUpDown` (as they should). As I said above, this is not the orthodox Windows style. The UpDown that I create using Win32 API directly is looking exactly as needed, but the Edit doesn't. Delphi's `TSpinEdit` is also a joke. I mean, look at those arrows. I don't like that.

Comment: @andlabs, are you saying that I should have something else instead of `'EDIT'` in the `CreateWindowEx`'s parameters? Or I should somehow force another version of Common Controls DLL to load?

Comment: @J.Middson does your app have a [ComCtl32 v6 manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx) to enable visual styles? Which version of Delphi are you using? If you are using Tnt controls, then you are using a pre-Unicode version, at least. For really old versions, use [Soft-Gems XP Theme Manager](http://soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) (which has incorporated into the VCL directly in a later version).

Comment: @andlabs, thanks to you I came up with an idea. I've replaced `'EDIT'` in the `CreateWindowEx`'s parameters with `'ComboBox'`, and now things got a little better. The border is not 3D, it's how it should be. The UpDown buttons are outside of the edit though, and they have a white outline around them. But, well, this looks (a little) better than the previous two options anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I use Delphi 7 and I didn't put such manifest myself, so probably it's not there. I will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am guessing the manifest is there because the updown itself is themed...

Comment: @andlabs don't assume. Look in the EXE's resources to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message is improperly handled. For example, an invalid brush is returned.